# Next js getServerSideProps sometimes not called

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm building a frontend application for e-commerce project and I'm using React 17.x and Nextjs 10.2.3. My problem is when I change page with next/link getServerSideProps doesn't called but when I refresh the page getServerSideProps called and sending request to backend. I looked to documentation of next/link it's says next/link has a shallow property for calling getServerSideProps for pre-fetching or not and I turned that property to false but still getServerSideProps doesn't called with next/link. Is there any way except not using next/link?

One page of my project

```
interface HomeProps {
  announcements: IAnnouncement[];
  campaigns: ICampaignResponse[];
  companies: ICompaniesResponse[];
  creditSummary: ICreditResponse;
}
export const getServerSideProps = async (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext
) => {
  const announcements = await queryEndpoints.getAnnouncements();
  const creditSummary = await queryEndpoints.getCredit();
  const companies = await queryEndpoints.getCompanies();
  const campaigns = await queryEndpoints.getCampaigns();
  return {
    props: {
      announcements,
      creditSummary,
      companies,
      campaigns,
    },
  };
};
export default function Home({
  companies,
  campaigns,
  creditSummary,
}: HomeProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <CampaignsBlock campaigns={campaigns} />
        <div className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 pt-18 pb-24">
          <div className="border border-gray-300 p-8 rounded-md col-start-1 col-end-13 lg:col-end-8 xl:col-end-8 order-2 lg:order-1 xl:order-1">
            <div className="w-full">
              <SectionHeader sectionHeading="Duyuru" />
              <p className="text-body text-xs lg:text-sm leading-normal xl:leading-relaxed">
                Monochrome elegance. Made with a relaxed wide-leg, these
                trousers are made from a sustainable soft organic cotton with a
                mechanical stretch making the garment easily recycled.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-start-1 col-end-13 lg:col-start-8 xl:col-start-8 order-1  lg:order-2 xl:order-2">
            <CreditsBlock creditSummary={creditSummary} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <CompaniesBlock companies={companies} />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```